# Cannot view images in Xcode

Tags: xcode, image, view

I seems to be unable to view images in Xcode. I am not talking about when running an app, nor do I mean UIImageViews (that works) or other views with images set (also works) in Interface Builder, I am simply talking about viewing images by clicking on them in the project navigator (in the left pane) and expecting them to show up on the middle/right (just like when editing code).

Has anyone had this problem as well?

Comment: tried the media library within xcode?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is fullscreen mode. If you exit the fullscreen the images is previewed as expected.

Comment: Well, didn't see that one coming.

Comment: I have noticed Xcode 5.1 no longer exhibits this behaviour, so I guess now the answer is to upgrade.

Answer (score 1):

Check this menu and be sure you select Preview :

[image]

Comment: HEX "works", as in, I see a giant field of HEX values. Preview just gives me an empty gray pane. Thanks for the suggestion, though.

Comment: @pancake: are you sure the image is not a transparent or plain-gray. And which version of Xcode are you using?